# SQL Join 2 tables on match and then find missing value in table 3

Tags: sql

Table1 (Master Office Address)

```
Office | City | Country2Letter | Country3Letter | Address

US Chicago West Wacker | Chicago | US | USA | 111 West Wacker

US New York 11 Madison | New York | US | USA | 11 S Madison

US Detroit Jefferson Ave | Detroit | US | USA | 24 Jefferson Ave
```

Table2 (Some Office are correct and some are not)

```
SamAccountName | Office | BrandCode

dsmith | US Chicago West Wacker | RES

jdoe | US New York 11 Madison | DIG

msmith | US Detroit Jefferson Ave | DIG
```

Table3

```
DLName | OfficeName | BrandCode

US Chicago West Wacker | US Chicago West Wacker | RES

US New York 11 Madison | US New York 11 Madison | DIG
```

So I want to ensure that the OfficeName comes from the master Table1 and include any individuals from Table2 with a match.  Then I want to display any missing items from table 3 which don't have a BrandCode with that OfficeName.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, avoid using OfficeName as a column. the reference should be officeId which will allow better query performance.

your query will be somewhat like this

```
select table2.* from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.officeId=t2.officeId
select table3.* from table3 t3 where t3.officeId not in (<query above>)
```